# htaccess use "this.php" if the above conditions are not met

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an already existing php scripts, and recently I wanted to integrate Slim framework.

What I hope to attain is use the Slim routing as the final resort if all my already existing Rewrite Conditions are not met, it means Slim will handle 404 pages too.

Slim framework .htaccess rewrite rule is:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

but because I already have existing `index.php` I instantiated Slim using `this.php` instead, so it should be

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ this.php [QSA,L]`

Here comes the problem, I already have pre-existing rewrite rules that I want to keep, here are some rewrite rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc,l]

RewriteRule     ^category/([^/]*)/?$    category.php?console=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$  category.php?console=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^category-amp/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$  category-amp.php?console=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^games/([^/]*)/?$   games.php?console=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule     ^forum^(.*)$ index.php 
RewriteRule     ^download.php?$ $1/new-page$2 [R=301,L]
```

so if any of the pattern above was not met, I wish them to use `this.php` instead.

If I add

`RewriteRule ^ this.php [QSA,L]`

to the bottom of the rules. The problem is, upon using it, every rule above was ignored, cause all queries to redirect to `this.php`, which would throw Slim's 404 errors. How can I make htaccess to check first if the rules set above `RewriteRule ^ this.php [QSA,L]` to match first before passing it finally to `this.php`?

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way by keeping slim rule at the bottom:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^download\.php$ /new-page [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/?$ category.php?console=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ category.php?console=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category-amp/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ category-amp.php?console=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^games/([^/]*)/?$ games.php?console=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^forum index.php [L]

# slim rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ this.php [L]
```

Comment: can you please explain why its `[L]` and not the original `[QSA,L]`?

Comment: `QSA` is needed only when you're modifying query string in target URI and here in this rule we're not doing that.